# Magento nested cms variables

Tags: magento, variables, block

I would like to know if it is possible to do the following:

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" button_label="GET {{CustomVar code='discount-percent'}}% OFF" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

This code print the custom variable but not the block.
Is there any way to print the block along with the custom variable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No. You cannot add any PHP code to a CMS Page in magento. You need to add any php code into that template file you're referencing, or you can create a new template file to do any php scripting you need done, then have the value passed back into the CMS Page (if needed).

For example, create a new phtml file named mynewpage.phtml and call that file in the CMS page:

```
{{block type='core/template' template='mynewpage.phtml'}}
```

Then in that file, it looks like you might be trying to get a query parameter, so you might want something like this:

```
echo '$_GET["myparam"]';
```